# scrollbar moves rough when activating fastscrollenable in android listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-scrollbar, fastscroll

scrollbar moves roughly while scrolling. how to make scrollbar move smoothly when enable fastcrollenable="true"?

I've been looking for it for a month. both in android documentation, stackoverflow, and other web ,but i can't find it.

in my listview , im just add....

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(boolean enabled)
When smooth scrollbar is enabled, the position and size of the scrollbar thumb is 
computed based on the number of visible pixels in the visible items.
```

note that sometimes your answer would be easily found in java